# Swiper slider container height

Tags: jquery, css, slider

so..I'm using swiper slider with bootstrap to create a vertical template.
Each slide have a background image and a container witch contains 2 or 3 smaller images.

I'm using the bootstrap grid system for displaying those 2-3 images on the slider.
but the problem is that the container is not the same height as the slider itself.

On some themes that uses the verticall template, i saw that the container got the height of the slider and when you shrink the screen it automatically updates the height.
Got any ideas how can i achive this ?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you please provide some code of what you have tried so far and maybe an image of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: so actually i want to know how can i center vertically the "container" in swiper slider.

Comment: Have you checked this [demo](http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/03-vertical.html) and its [source](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/blob/master/demos/03-vertical.html)?